# html table in IE and chrome

Tags: html, html-table

I would like to ask why there is rendering difference between IE and chrome? 
I've a same html design width 200, rowspan=1, colspan=2 for each cell but why IE rendering out the layout not as expected.

How could I made the same results as in chrome to IE?
Sample jsbin: http://jsbin.com/facisunubo/edit?html,output

```
    <tr>
    <td class=noborder width=100 bgcolor=#DBDBDB></td>
    <td class=noborder width=100 bgcolor=#DBDBDB></td>
    <td nowrap colspan= 2 width= 200 rowspan= 1 > DH-10-18 </td>
    <td nowrap colspan= 2 width= 200 rowspan= 1 > DH-10-28 </td>
    <td nowrap colspan= 2 width= 200 rowspan= 1 > DH-10-38 </td>
    <td nowrap colspan= 2 width= 200 rowspan= 1 > DH-10-68 </td>
    <td class=noborder width=100></td>
    </tr>
```

Below are sample from IE and chrome.

[image: IE][image: Chrome]

Comment: Please clarify WHAT isn't working as you believe it should. Also, post the *relevant* HTML.

Comment: Hi, The expected output in IE is not what as expected. By right the layout should look exactly the same a in chrome. In IE, the cell "DH-10-18" should have 2 cells same as cell "DH-10-38". But from the looks, the size are not as expected. However, this issue does not happens in chrome.

Comment: That's the problem with supporting all the browsers you need make adjustments, maybe if you'd include your code, can help us help you.

Comment: I've updated my question with sample jsbin. I'm able to simulate my issue whereby the width of the cell is different in IE and chrome.